# I want to study all 613 Mitzvot in depth. Can someone recommend a good book for me to read dedicated to that topic?

Tags: halacha, commentaries, mitzvah, adult-learning, sefer-hachinuch

Other than the Mishnah and the Talmud , are there any books that give in-depth commentary, explanation, and context for each and every mitzvot? I'm only referring to books soley focused on the topic of the 613 mitzvot.

Comment: I found this book on amazon but I don't know if its high quality. 613 Mitzvot: A Contemporary Guide to the Commandments of Judaism https://a.co/d/j9brbem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a wonderful intention, I did it a few times both alone and with my daughter and it is a great way to acquire broad knowledge.

As Joel K indicated, the classic way to acquire this learning is through Sefer Hachinuch, which brings for each of the 613 mitzvot (according to the Rambam's list) its description, purpose (an innovation on its own since the Torah rarely describes it), a summary of its laws and to whom it applies.

Artscroll has a truly excellent elucidation that covers 10 volumes ([here](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422617236.html)) and is the gold standard in English. The challenge is that it is very broad and deep, and takes a few months of consistent learning.

Two ways to ease your learning and potentially help you decide whether to engage more deeply are

- the [Concise Sefer HaChinuch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598260197), an abbreviation written by R Asher Wasserman in one volume - I started there and found it an excellent start
- use the larger version but study only the commandments, which can be performed today (ca. 270 of the 613, see [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/541686/jewish/How-Many-of-the-Torahs-Commandments-Still-Apply.htm) and [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/9029)). The Chofetz Chaim has a small book describing those: [The Concise Book of Mitzvoth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0873064941). It can serve as a wonderful "appetizer" for the others

Comment: So helpful thank you very much! ✌️

Answer (score 4):

One of the classics is [Sefer HaChinuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch).

It's available online [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh?tab=contents) in Hebrew and English.